# InvokeMember("Click") in awesomium

Tags: c#, javascript, click, awesomium, invokemember

I want to InvokeMember("Click") in awesomium

i can do this when i have elementid or elementtag with somthing like this ;

```
JSObject document = webView.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult( "document" );

if ( document == null )
    return;

using ( document )
{
    JSObject signin = document.Invoke( "getElementById", "signin" );

    if ( signin == null )
        return;

    using ( signin )
        signin.InvokeAsync( "click" );
}
```

but i want to that when i have not any element , i need only  Invoke "Click" in webpage for running java script code which opening pop up page with mouse click....

have any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

```
webView.ExecuteJavascript(@"$('#signin').trigger('click');");
```

Comment: i don't test this code , but i want to know , what is #signin it's element no ? or we create this element and then click ? what happen ?

Comment: `#signin` is the selector syntax for an element with an id of "signing".  It is similar to your call to `document.getElementById('signin')`

Comment: So it's not good for me ! bcs i have not any element id or Tag and i don't need to click on special element i want only click like when we click on empty page....Now do you know what can i do ? (thnx, Kind regards)

Comment: I guess `webView.ExecuteJavascript(@"$(document.body).trigger('click');");` is what you need.  This seems pointless though.